# split the date then divide it into three columns

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I have a column for a date in this format 2/21/2020, and 11/2/2020

what I mean if it the month 2 it will be one digit if it is 11 two digits

the result that I need from the above examples should be like 20200221 and 20201102

so I decided to split the date and divide them into three columns be like year:2020 month:02 day:21

then I will combine them

```
year || month || day
```

now I know how to split the year

```
select
       regexp_substr(date1, '[^/]+$', 1, 1) as year
from (select '2/11/2020' as date1 from dual)
```

but if I need the month or the day what I should change in the code

In addition, If the month contains one digit, the 0 should be added beside the month number like 02. do I use case when condition?

Is there any easier way to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column is of date datatype then

```
To_char(your_date_column, 'yyyymmdd')
```

If your column is of varchar datatype then

```
To_char(to_date(your_date_column_in_string,'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'yyyymmdd')
```

Dont worry about one or two digit in day or month as oracle is smart enough to recognize it.

See this [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4ecdde5b7c78f12a532be585fe0b6767)

Comment: you are amazing! this easier than I thought. thank you again

Answer (score 2):

Try this hope you like it.

```
declare @TargetDate datetime='2/21/2020'
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar,(SELECT @TargetDate),23), '-', '') as Date;
```